# Get XUL browser language where the component is running

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to know if there is a way to get the actual locale of the browser where my component is running (en-EN, es-ES,ru-RU,etc...) so that I can test the different locales of a file I have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how i know how to do it: `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.navigator.language`